# How to change which "section" a java source file opens up in in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have rearranged and customized the Eclipse layout to exactly how I like it. But whenever I open up a java source file, it opens up in the box with Package Explorer and Outline instead of the big box on the left where I would like it to (see screenshot). How can I change this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of it "doing it wrong"?  The one you posted seems "correct" in that the file "NumericQuestion.java" is indeed open on the big left panel...

Comment: It looks like you messed around with the "Shared area". You should probably reset your perspective (Window / Reset perspective), and then try again to move the Package Explorer and the Outline to the right, but make sure you do not drag and drop them inside the "Title" zone of the "Shared area". If you do so, classes will open there as well like you described. Hope this helps.

Comment: Inserted image inline

Comment: Pedro Lopez fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to fix it:

"It looks like you messed around with the "Shared area". You should probably reset your perspective (Window / Reset perspective), and then try again to move the Package Explorer and the Outline to the right, but make sure you do not drag and drop them inside the "Title" zone of the "Shared area". If you do so, classes will open there as well like you described. Hope this helps." –  Pedro Lopez